# How to draw a beam or frame system in Latex

Tags: plot

(hopefully not a duplicated QS)

how can we draw a beam or frame systems in Latex **in an easy way**?

For example, we may see the following figure as reference

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need anything special for this. Here is a start, up to two unreadable labels it reproduces the left diagram.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=#1},
    bullet/.default=2pt,
    pics/barslash/.style={code={\draw (-#1,-#1) -- (#1,#1) (0,-#1) -- (0,#1);}},
    pics/barslash/.default=1ex]
 \draw[thick] (0,0) -- node[left] {$2E\ell c$} ++ (0,2)
    -| node[pos=0.25,bullet=4pt,label=above:$2m$]{} 
     node[right,pos=0.75] {$2E\ell c$} ++ (3,-2);
 \draw[thick] (0,2) -- node[left] {$E\ell c$} ++ (0,2)
    -| node[pos=0.25,bullet=2pt,label=above:$m$]{} 
     node[right,pos=0.75] {$E\ell c$} ++ (3,-2);
 \draw(0,-1) -- pic[pos=0]{barslash} pic[pos=1]{barslash} 
     node[above]{$L=2h$} ++ (3,0);   
 \draw(-1.5,0) -- ++ (0,4) foreach \X in {0,0.5,1} 
    {pic[pos=\X,sloped,xscale=-1]{barslash}}
    foreach \X in {0.25,0.75} 
    { node[pos=\X,left]{$h$}} ;  
 \path[pattern=north east lines] (-0.25,0) edge ++ (0.5,0) rectangle ++ (0.5,-0.25)
    (2.75,0) edge ++ (0.5,0) rectangle ++ (0.5,-0.25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]